# cakephp date 'dmy' validdation is not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to validate with `dmy` format. Here is what I wrote in my model:

```
'birthdate' => array(
    'date' => array(
        'rule' => array('date','dmy'),
        'message' => 'Solo data valida',
        'allowEmpty' => true,
    )
)
```

However, when I submit the form with the date, I get an error.

Comment: how about telling us what you have submitted, how you are saving and the actual error that has been shown?

Comment: <?php echo $this->Form->input('birthdate', array('label' => false,'maxlength' => '200', 'div' => false, 'id' => 'datepicker', 'type' => 'text','placeholder' => "GG-MM-AAAA")); ?> this is the input field but it's not validate when I submit with a date as for example 02-02-1985. it's shows the message 'Solo data valida'

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should verify is the value of "birthday" DIRECTLY PRIOR to validation. Try debugging $this->request->data in your controller before calling $this->Model->save, or $this->Model->validate. It's quite possible that you are transforming that date value before you pass it to validation, and thus it could be failing.

For instance, I typically use a beforeSave, and afterFind callback to transform dates going into and coming from MySQL, or you may have something in your appController or beforeFilter callback that's inadvertently transforming the data.